# SQLPlus Exporting column with multiple rows in one cell to csv file

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, sqlplus

I've looked everywhere and no luck.

I have a simple select statement. (Select Col1 from dbtbl).
Returning cells with multiple rows in each cell (using || chr(10)) to format them. 
In plsql it looks ok. But since I must export it using sqlplus, when exporting, to csv it sees chr(10) as a new table row instead of new cell row.
Is there anyway I can export it so that it sees it as a new cell row?

I'm separating my columns with commas ','
(I've tried replacing chr(10) with '\n' - but it just displays \n characters in excel file.)

Code:

```
Select 'row1'A || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'row1B' || ',' 'row2 from dual;
```

The results should have row1A and row1B in the first cell and row2 and the second cell.

Comment: Please post your code. Not conversational references to the code. The code. We need to see code to fix code.

Answer (score 0):

try adding carriage return chr(13) + chr(10)